# Firefox li href CSS selector

Tags: css, firefox

I've styled some list items (li) using CSS. The style's applied to the a selector within the li. It works great in Chrome, IE and Safari but not Firefox:

```
<ul class="organisations">
   <li class="community-care"><a href="http://adviceglos.org.uk/organisation-type/community-care/" title="View all posts in Community Care" >Community Care</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
ul.organisations li.community-care a {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,center top,center bottom,color-stop(0%,#5CBCC4),color-stop(100%,#38939B));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5CBCC4 0,#38939B 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#5CBCC4 0,#38939B 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#5CBCC4 0,#38939B 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#5CBCC4 0,#38939B 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(#5CBCC4 0,#38939B 100%);
background-color: #5CBCC4;
border: 1px solid #318188;
border-bottom-color: #245E63;
}
```

Comment: it's work fine what's problem http://tinkerbin.com/Oq9QB8db

Comment: how exactly does it not work? what is the resulting display in firefox?

Comment: The resulting display is that the base styles show but the gradients don't. Here's the web address http://adviceglos.org.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your stylesheet.  In particular, line 529 is:

```
background-image: -o-linear-gradient((#eeeeee 0,#ccc 100%) !important;
```

Note that you have one more open paren than close paren.  In a spec-compliant CSS parser (which excludes WebKit), this causes the UA to treat everything up to the matching close paren as part of the background-image value. In this case, that's all the rest of the stylesheet, so all the rules after this point are ignored.

Further note that Firefox did report this problem in its error console, which is how I found it...

Comment: You are an absolute star! Thanks so much for your response, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `-moz` for firefox like this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#BF698C 0px, #93506D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```